# How to perform htaccess rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

Here is the summary of my problem.

I have created a Facebook like button. It works correctly most of the time, however not when following the link from somebody's actual "like" post. It seems that Facebook is adding some more info to the URL. For instance, I have

www.example.com/blog.php/6

but Facebook adds

www.example.com/blog.php/6?fb_action_ids=10201090685057512&fb_action_types=og.likes&fb_source=aggregation&fb_aggregation_id=288381481237582

When a user follows this link they get a Mysql syntax error. If they follow the first link there is no problem. I thought I could just strip off all that extra text from the URL.

I created a .htaccess file and placed it in my root directory on GoDaddy.
I Tried several different rewrites.

Nothing has worked. This is the latest thought I tried:
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*&)?fb_action_ids=
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1?%1 [R=301]

Do I need to change my .htaccess file or is there another way to solve this problem?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: It might be more useful to know what the mysql error is and why it would be running with get vars in place

Comment: Here is the error. However, this error is only seen when arriving at the page from the fb_action link and not the blog.php/6 link.You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?fb_action_ids=10201090685057512&fb_action_types=og.likes&fb_source=aggregation&' at line 1

Comment: Ok so are you fetching data by exploding the url or something? You should update your answer with how you're extracting the 6 from the url. You can achieve this with htaccess but it might be a good idea to see how you construct the code. you might be inviting an exploit of some kind

Comment: I use the following which may be why the fb_ portion messes up the rest of the code as I am not expecting that extra stuff just a number that points to a blog post id: /* Looks at text after last "/" */
/* This is the post_id of the selected blog from the main page */
$title=basename($site_load);

Comment: you may want to split on that ? then. What happens if that id is something like "6';DROP TABLE users;" - Since you get that mysql error it suggests you're not sanitizing your input

Comment: Sorry, I am not really sure what you mean by the above comment. The post id will always be a number.

Comment: no it won't. If I can see the url I can post anything I want to it, or in your case just navigate directly to it since it is depending on the url. If it wasn't, you wouldn't be getting the get var errors. If that makes no sense, I would recommend posting the actual code that builds the query in your question and not as inline text in these comments. I'm not trying to make trouble or anything. Just saying your whole issue may not just be a simple mod rewrite request

Comment: I figured it out: just changed how I request the url:$site_load=strtok($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],'?');